# Locking focus to a window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding a disclosure window to the start of my application. I want the window to be the only window that the user can interact with until it is closed. I have googled the heck out of it and have come up empty.

Thanks,

Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want modal dialog maybe? See [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method.

For example:

---

App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication3.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup" />
```

---

App.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var w = new YourDisclosureWindowClass();
        w.ShowDialog();
        // whatever you need to run you entire application
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks, just want I needed.