# Locking user to browser window (using .dll files)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, npapi

Is it possible to lock a user in chrome using .dll files (NPAPI plugin) or any other method?

I want to invoke chrome browser in highly controlled environment preferably on Windows. I would download [chrome for businesses](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/chromebrowser.html) and write policies such that user isn't allowed to access any url except one.

I would create a packaged app and create an application shortcut on desktop for user which goes to the url. So it will open in KIOSK mode. But I would want that user shouldn't be able to navigate away from chrome, specifically that window and shouldn't be able to use any other program until he logs out of the application or explicitly closes the window. That means disabling function /ctrl/alt and window keys.
Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887240/locking-focus-to-a-window-wpf) but with chrome.

Even opening chrome itself in 'locked' mode is not a problem.

Has someone ever implemented it? Is it possible using NPAPI plugin or any other method? If anybody could direct me towards any such resources I would be grateful.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Group Policies or other mechanisms of your *operating system* to enforce kiosk-only mode?

Comment: My problem is not running it in Kiosk mode, that can be done. What I want to accomplish is 'lock the user' into the window and disallow minimizing the window or access any other programs on user's computer until the window is closed. Is there a mechanism in _Operating Systems_ to accomplisht this. Particularly Windows or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not realistically possible using an NPAPI plugin, at least not by itself. At minimum you'd need an extension (see http://npapi.com/extensions).

If you loaded it from an extension it might be possible to get the window handle of the browser and such, but I think you'd probably be better off with a separate app.